# Under what conditions can we find a sequence of smooth functions that converge to a particular $C^k$ function?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

When studying a particular function $f \in C^k(\Omega)$ it seems useful to be able to find a sequence of smooth functions $f_n$ such that $f_n \rightarrow f$ in $C^k$. I am familiar with the Stone Weierstrass Theorem, but under what conditions can this result be generalized to arbitrary smooth functions?

So my question is suppose $f \in C^k(\Omega)$. Under what conditions can we find smooth $\{f_k\}$ such that $f_k \rightarrow f$ in $C^k$? Are there any conditions on $\Omega$ (could it even be all of $\mathbb{R}^n$ or must it have compact support)? On $f$ (must it also have compact support?)? Can this be done for any $k$? Is there a name for this result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The set of smooth with compact support has really nice properties, it is dense in lots of spaces such as $L^p (\Omega)$ for $1\leqslant p< \infty$ but for $p = \infty $, we have a weaker result, it is dense in $C^0(\bar{\Omega})$, the space of continuous functions vanishing on the border of $\Omega$ and which limit to infinity is $0$ (otherwise the distance would not even be finite).

The proof uses convolution with what is called in French "approximations de l'unité" (maybe unity approximations) which are positive compact support smooth functions $p_n$ which verify $\int p = 1$ and $f \ast p_n (x) \rightarrow f(x)$. To do so, you can take a plateau function and stretch it to become more and more like a Dirac.

Convolution is very powerful and the convolution of any function with a regular fonction gives a regular fonction (it keeps the most regular of both) but does not preserves support, hence you must first prove that smooth compact support functions are dense in $C^\infty (\bar{\Omega})$.

For references, I have some in French like:

https://www.ljll.math.upmc.fr/MathModel/enseignement/polycopies/ledret-chapitre0.pdf

But any book about functional analysis will work.

Note that for $p = \infty$ you won't have convergence of the derivatives, otherwise it would imply that $f$ is smooth. BUT you can have a similar result for $C^k(\bar{\Omega})$ with the convergence of each derivative of order $\leqslant k$, it is equivalent to the first one!

Comment: Thank you! So the restriction on $\Omega$ in the case of $C^k$ is that it must be closed?

Comment: Not closed but bounded if you want convergence on any smooth function. However you can probably fin other metrics for which it works...

Comment: Got it, thank you!

Comment: Edito: maybe not metrics but topologies for sure (weak convergence eg)